# How to open and adit such file?

Tags: database, sqlite, file

I have export file with products and history data. I need to change information about products storage number. Here is example file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RAC73jM3pbrlbYVaAQL58vN9SvnBvNxM

File looks like it contains another files. Any idea what format is this, how I can open it and edit? Looks kinda like packaged sqlite files or something.

[image]

Comment: Where did this file come from?

Comment: Export from app to manage storage, invoices, accounting. Complex app to manage your business. There is a new law in my country and we must do some modifications to that file (change values), so we can import it again.

Comment: Why did you tag sqllite? is this from sqllite? Without knowing the application it's anyones guess. Seems like you need to do a bit more investigation into this mystery application.

Comment: Well, believe me or not, I did. I tagged it like that because there were few files that was like sqllite. This was shot that maybe someone more clever than me will have any idea to solve this or where to find solution/help. Program is old, maintained from DOS version.

Comment: If the program is old enough that you mention DOS then it is unlikely to be SQLite, maybe DBase or something similarly ancient. And the export is likely specific to that app so you should start by reading the app's source code (assuming it still exists :)